# Salt-cloud docker state, handle volumes

Tags: docker, saltstack, disk-volume

I'm using [dockerio salt state](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerio.html#module-salt.states.dockerio) to startup docker containers on a salt minion. Trying to mount volumes into my container is failing. Container is starting but volumes are not bound. What am I missing?

Aiming for this:

```
sudo docker run \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
  --volume=/sys/fs/cgroup/:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  google/cadvisor
```

**cadvisor sls file**

```
cadvisor-image:
   docker.pulled:
     - name: google/cadvisor
     - tag: latest
     - require_in: cadvisor-container
     - force: True

cadvisor-container:
   docker.installed:
     - name: cadvisor
     - hostname: cadvisor
     - image: google/cadvisor
     - ports:
       - "8080/tcp"
     - volumes:
       - /var/run:/var/run
       - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup
       - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker
     - require_in: cadvisor

cadvisor:
   docker.running:
     - container: cadvisor
     - port_bindings:
            "8080/tcp":
                HostIp: ""
                HostPort: "8080"
     - binds:
       /var/run:
         bind: /var/run
         rw: true
       /sys/fs/cgroup:
         bind: /sys/fs/cgroup
       /var/lib/docker:
         bind: /var/lib/docker
```

**Versions**

```
love@master:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

love@master:~$ salt server01 cmd.run "docker version"
server01:
    Client version: 1.1.1
    Client API version: 1.13
    Go version (client): go1.2.1
    Git commit (client): bd609d2
    Server version: 1.1.1
    Server API version: 1.13
    Go version (server): go1.2.1
    Git commit (server): bd609d2

love@master:~$ salt server01 cmd.run "salt-minion --version"
server01:
    salt-minion 2014.1.7

love@master:~$ salt --version
salt 2014.1.7
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about the environment (host OS / version, Docker version)?

Comment: updated with versions @AndyShinn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salt docs are wrong and doesn't reflects [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py#using-volumes) interface as pointed out in [this comment on GitHub](https://serverfault.com/questions/606099/salt-cloud-docker-state-handle-volumes). Trailing slash was missing.

```
     - binds:
      /var/run/:
        bind: /var/run
        ro: False
      /sys/fs/cgroup/:
        bind: /sys/fs/cgroup
        ro: True
      /var/lib/docker/:
        bind: /var/lib/docker
        ro: True
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an indentation issue where you defined your 'binds'.  Try indenting it two spaces further so the nested dicts are indented past the parent namespace, not just the parent list item.

See: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerio.html#salt.states.dockerio.running

```
- binds:
    /var/log/service: /var/log/service
```

Comment: I did try that today, with updated config, I've updated the question with the latest tested sls. Also created a ticket in [salt github](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/14089)